# Can you play video games in heaven?

Tags: game

You can do whatever you want in heaven right including playing video games with your friends that get to heaven. I have heard that your thoughts or whatever are purified once you are in heaven and you won't want to look at pornography or anything so does this apply to games? I know this might be a genuinely stupid but I am just curious about it.

Comment: Believe me, you will never even think of video games, you will think and that will be a reality, you can think of some game and you will be in that game!

Answer (score 5):

In heaven, there is what eyes didn't see, what ears didn't hear, and what no human being can ever imagine. When you see that, video games would be boring.

if in heaven there are things you can't imagine then, imagine being inside the game playing in a virtual world with your friends. Heaven has something even better that you can't imagine.

God says in the Quran 43:71
"..And therein is whatever the souls desire.."

WHATEVER YOU DESIRE. you have earned it